# Printing results of basic math without assignment to a variable - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm working with a larger program, but what I'm really struggling with is printing the result of simple math expressions.  It doesn't seem necessary that I have to assign them to a variable.  I have tried a few combinations of `print` / `int` / `str`.

I've looked at the following questions:

- [Print out math expression contained within variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883908/print-out-math-expression-contained-within-variable)
- [How do I print the results of my math of my functions? [python functions] (edited)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826851/how-do-i-print-the-results-of-my-math-of-my-functions-python-functions-edite)
- [How to evaluate a math expression given in string form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)
- [basic math rotation, wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832647/basic-math-rotation-wrong-results)

I've also done several searches.

```
list_options = ("hammer", "rope", "blanket", "sunglasses")
print (list_options)
print()
r1 = len(list_options)
r2 = (random.randint(1, r1) +1)

print(r1)
print(r2)
print()
print ("Python range is 1 to " + r2 + "Technically range is 1 to " )
print(int(r2-1))
```

Comment: Have you tried [fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what that is, but I'll look it up.  So as of the time of typing - nope, not yet.  (Thank you for the link.)

Comment: Wow.  That's a good learning site, with a lot of information to unpack.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5:

```
print('1 + 1 = %d' % (1 + 1))
print('1 + 1 = {sum}'.format(sum=(1+1)))
```

Python 3.6-3.7:

```
print(f'1 + 1 = {1 + 1}')
```

Python 3.8:

```
f'{1 + 1=}'
```